# Upload Package issue

Tags: managed-package, package

While doing Managed package upload I am getting the following Error.

Page 'SiteTemplate.apexp' exposes public remoted methods in component 'NameSpace__FileName[image]' that are not in the same namespace as the page

I need help in fixing this issue.

Comment: Please add some more details with this issue. what is your package name? what is the component name you have inside that vf page.

Comment: We are  using a 3rd party app for payment and appointment booking process which is using @RemoteAction.

Comment: Found this from a while ago although it is not very clear. Maybe remote the sitetemplate from your package? https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AVT1IAO